# How to remove Android stock movie player as preferred default app for movies?

Tags: default-applications

Using ASTRO File Manager, I've set Movies (stock Android app) to play my videos. Now I want to remove this association, but I simply can't find a way to do it.

Looking into applications didn't help (The Movies app doesn't show at all, I think it's part of the Gallery app, but the gallery app isn't set as default). I've tried downloading an app from market called [DefaultApp Reset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pxlib.android.defaultappset) but it didn't help either: Movies was not there.

Any hints?

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: Acer Liquid Metal (s120)

Comment: Try it with a **Default App Manager.** See [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14231/how-can-i-get-a-overview-and-manage-the-default-applications-for-file-types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem. Solved it by clearing defaults in my Gallery application.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you would do this from `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`.  Find the app in the list, click it, and choose Clear Defaults.

Comment: As I wrote in the question the main problem is that I can't find the "Movies" application to clear its default

Comment: It's probably called media player or video player.

Comment: It is not there.
I've passed apps one by one...

Comment: @Pitto Hmm. Maybe if you installed another video player, it would allow you to select a new default?

Comment: @Pitto: Make sure you are looking at all apps (including system), not just downloaded ones.  On Android 2.1 and below, once on the "Manage applications" screen, press Menu and select "All".

Comment: Ah, yes. In 2.2 (at least on my SGS) there's an "All" tab.

Comment: I've tried installing Nemo Player with this idea but I start to think it's really an android setting...
Looks like some kind of Astro setting but I've tried to uninstall and reinstall it without solving :(

Answer (score 3):

Just...

- go to *settings → applications → manage applications*
- select the *All* tab
- scroll down and find Gallery
- open this entry, tap the *clear defaults* button

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings->Manage Apps. Click option(overflow) key and select "Reset app preferences".

This will reset all default apps.

Answer (score -5):

It's not the best I could do but installing brand new Gingerbread (obviously) solved the problem