# How to change file associations in Android?

Tags: file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a overview and manage the default applications for file types?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14231/how-can-i-get-a-overview-and-manage-the-default-applications-for-file-types)

How to change file associations in Android? I have video files opening in one player but I want another.

Please don't propose

Settings => Manage Applications => The app you want to remove as default => clear default.

since I don't know the name of the player application name which is currently associated with video files.

I need file-type-centric solution.