# How to associate a file extension with an app?

Tags: applications, usb, file-management, files, default-applications

I have a number of files with some extension and I have an app that can open the files - it is not the default format of this app, but it can import and display it.

At the moment when I attach USB stick with these files File Manager display error message "This file cannot be opened".

I need to open the app, choose "File -> Import" navigate through fairly complex directory structure and only than I can see the content.

How to create file association so I can immediately open the file from File Manager?

Comment: Hmm, I've installed the up but I do not see the option to associate a file with an app. Can you please how exactly achieve the desired effect with his app?

Comment: But where shall I tap? When I tap the file in File Explorer I get the message "This file cannot be open".

Comment: Related: [How to assign default app to unlisted file type](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176951/how-to-assign-default-app-to-unlisted-file-type/176953#176953)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying various options I finally found the app that works for me. Total Commander has a number of associations and also allows you to associate a file with any app. Therefore I simply always use tc for browsing files and voila, it works.