# How can I force the file-app association in Samsung Files?

Tags: files, samsung-one-ui

On a One UI 5 / Android 13 tablet, I have some Krita files and despite having Krita installed, Samsung Files tells me I have no app to open this file type and I should search in the Play store.

Even going through all the hoops by uninstalling Krita and clicking on "Search" when this prompt appears, reinstalling it, does not help.

Also, "open with" does not show any app available.

How can I force a file-app association?

Btw. the association is in the APK's manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.kra.*"/>
            <data android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.krz.*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.kra.*"/>
            <data android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.krz.*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How to associate a file extension with an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180654/44325), [How to assign default app to unlisted file type](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/176951/44325). I'm not sure if it's possible with Samsung Files...

Comment: May be this Krita app is simply not designed to used this way or you simply use the wrong file extension. Developers have to register file extensions in their app. If they don't do this then how should the other apps know which app can be used to open which file type. Have you contacted the Krita developers and asked if this is a supported way?

Comment: @Robert I looked into the APK / AndroidManifest.xml and there you can see the file extension registered. Also, the file association works on another tablet.