# Oreo: associating an app with all files with a given extension?

Tags: file-management, files

**NOTE:** my question is indeed similar to the question above. However, there is a slight difference, which I explain below in my ADDENDUM section.

Original question ...

I am creating lots of text files on my Oreo-based Android device with various file extensions besides simply `.txt`. For example, I have files with `.xyz` extensions, `.abc` extensions, and others, and I want all files with these particular suffixes to be seen as text files by my chosen text editor app. This way, whenever I select such a file, the system will choose that text editor to open them.

I have not found any way to do this, especially given that there is no default file association for text files that is offered in Android. But even if such a default text-file association were to exist, I don't know how to cause *ad hoc* filename suffixes to be associated with text files.

Furthermore, intents seem to operate on mime types, and I don't know how to associate these extra suffixes with `text/plain` under Android.

Is there any way in Android (Oreo) for me to accomplish what I want?

Thank you in advance.

**ADDENDUM:** The post referenced above talks about how mime types are managed on an application-specific basis in Android, and that there is no official way to manage mime types on a system-wide basis.

I understand this, but I am asking something slightly different. Suppose an application is already configured in its manifest to respond to `text-plain` items. My question is this: where in Android is the `.txt` suffix defined as corresponding to `text-plain`, and is there any way to add more suffixes (such as `.abc` and `.xyz`, as I describe above) on a system-wide basis to also be mapped to `text-plain`?

I have a rooted device that makes use of `Xposed` and `Magisk`, and so even if there is no *official* way in Android to implement these kinds of mappings, I'm wondering if there might be any unofficial `Xposed` or `Magisk` modules that will enable this. I couldn't find any such `Xposed` or `Magisk` modules, but perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Also, since my device is rooted (and I also am able to change my selinux settings to `permissive`), I could manually edit system configuration files anywhere on the device to add more filename suffixes to the `text-plain` mapping, assuming that this mapping is indeed managed in some sort of system configuration file.

I also run `Tasker`, and if such a mime configuration file exists, I could make sure that `Tasker` always copies a special version of that file in place during boot-up. In addition, I run other utitilies which allow *ad hoc* scripts to be run at startup via `init.d`.

Any thoughts? ...

Comment: Use a different file manager (e.g. Solid Explorer), it lets you choose from different apps to open those kind of file extension

Comment: Thank you, but I want to associate `plain/text` with these items even if they are opened outside of a file manager ... *i.e.*, via an arbitrary app. Is that not possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign default app to unlisted file type](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176951/how-to-assign-default-app-to-unlisted-file-type)

Comment: It's not a dubplicate, because that post talks about how to configure the manifest file of a given app that is being developed so that it can recognize "unlisted" file types. What I want is to map an ad hoc suffix (for example, ".abc") to *always* be considered to be text/plain for *all* apps that I will ever run on my device.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks like a promising answer ...

The file `/system/lib/content-types.properties` contains the following info. It looks like I can add `abc=text/plain` and `xyz=text/plain` to this file in order to get my desired behavior. I'll test this and report back.

```
# If you want to support more recognized mimetypes in libcore.net.MimeUtils, add them here

docm=application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12
xlsb=application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12
xlsm=application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12
ppsm=application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroenabled.12
ppsx=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
pptm=application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12

asm=text/x-asm
cc=text/x-c
conf=text/plain
cpp=text/x-c
css=text/css
c=text/x-c
cxx=text/x-c
def=text/plain
dic=text/x-c
f77=text/x-fortran
f90=text/x-fortran
for=text/x-fortran
f=text/x-fortran
hh=text/x-c
hpp=text/x-c
h=text/x-c
ics=text/calendar
ifb=text/calendar
in=text/plain
jad=text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor
java=text/x-java-source
ksh=text/plain
list=text/plain
log=text/plain
pas=text/x-pascal
pl=text/plain
properties=|
prop=text/plain
p=text/x-pascal
py=text/x-python
rc=text/plain
sgml=text/sgml
sgm=text/sgml
s=text/x-asm
vcs=text/x-vcalendar
```

Comment: Sadly, when I put entries such as `abc=text/plain` into this file, their existence seems to be ignored, even after I reboot the device. So ... back to the drawing board ...